# Just having some fun

Tags: cipher, steganography, lateral-thinking

> **To:** John (jpat@synopsis.io)
>   **From:** Anna (aeli@synopsis.io)
>   **CC:** All (all@synopsis.io)
>   **Subject:**  Just having some fun...

Hello, everyone! I decided to experiment with a few things lately. I have an image for you.
[image: animal.png]
Can you guess what my favorite animal is? Hopefully you can!
~ Anna

Comment: Can't resist...but should...but can't...A Lemur!?!

Comment: If the answer is "lemur", I'm going to be disappointed.

Comment: @IanMacDonald If it was lemur, I wouldn't post it :)

Comment: @DanRussell TEMPTATIONS ARE EVIL.

Comment: Is it a [Pale Fork-Marked Lemur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_fork-marked_lemur)? That text is kind of pale and looks like spaghetti that was pushed around by a fork.

Comment: Just confirming. An emu isn't an animal, is it?

Comment: @RipTide An emu is an animal.

Comment: Flightless bird...

Comment: @RipTide It's in the kingdom Animalia... I call it an animal.

Comment: I knew you'd get technical. Damn.

Comment: She sends mail directly to John and greets everyone. Mistake?

Comment: @nikamed Notice the CC (that's a line telling us that she's forwarding it to everyone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is:

> [Addax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addax)

Because:

> The image file includes a zip file (the rest of the data after the PNG's IEND chunk). The zip file contains a base64 (data.b6) encoded RIFF/WAV file and the word "ADDAX" can be found from the [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram).

Comment: Can you describe in more details the "magic" ? This answer (which may be true) is hardly believable without proper explanation.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The use of the word magic does indeed make my answer a bit dubious so I modified my answer towards a more proper explanation.

Comment: Animals are like pokemons : you think you know them all but there is always one you don't...

Comment: Good job! You solved the "case"!

Comment: @Anselmi n00b here, but do have any resources or tutorials on how one can learn to decode an image? My mind is blown by how you found the message

Answer (score 9):

Looks like it's

> A bunny

Because ...

> If we take the letters in the picture and rearrange them, it gives some kind of animal that resemble a bunny :
>
>
> [image: ![bunny picture made with the letters, with some black marks showing the ears and the eyes better.]]

Comment: If this is not the answer, I'm going to be disappointed :D

Comment: @ruddvan **ruudvan's dissapointment increases**

Comment: Not the correct answer, but I upvoted for creativity!

Answer (score 1):

Way off, but anyways:

> Le Mur, as in, The Wall? So, Animal Wall. A lemur is a primate. The only other primate on that wall is an ape. Soo.... Ape?

Comment: The picture doesn't have anything important... at first glance.